# How to override alert with Bootbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert, bootbox

I have a form that I am posting to a mysql database. I wish to override the alert function triggered by the [Malsup jQuery Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) with the alert created by [Bootbox plugin](http://bootboxjs.com/). 
Both the bootbox script and the jquery form work just fine but I don't know how to use them together as my knowledge of javascript and jquery is really limited.

Many thanks,

Julian

The Jquery form script.

```
<script> 
        // wait for the DOM to be loaded 
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
            $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
                alert("Your profile has been updated!"); 
            }); 
        }); 
    </script>
```

The Bootbox script.

```
bootbox.alert("Hello world!", function() {
  Example.show("Hello world callback");
});
```

Comment: Are you not able to run `bootbox.alert()` inside your `ajaxForm` function?

Comment: Well I thought about that and was wondering if the answer I need might lie in something like that but as I mentioned I'm a real novice at javascript I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: I figured it out, see code below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work just fine.

```
  <script> 
        // wait for the DOM to be loaded 
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
            $('#profile_form').ajaxForm(function() { 
             bootbox.alert("Your profile has been updated");
        }); 
 }); 
    </script>
```